# How to resolve the missing or invalid option in oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, record

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT on

declare
       type emp_record is record
       (v_empid emp1.empno % type;
        v_ename emp1.ename % type; )
emp_rec emp_record;
v_sal emp1.sal%type;

begin
v_sal:=:v_sal;

select empno,ename
into emp_rec
from emp1
where sal:=v_sal;

dbms_output.put_line('The employee whose salary is ' || v_sal || 'has Employee Id ' || emp_rec.v_empid || 'and his name is ' || emp_rec.v_ename); 
end;
```

The error is :

> ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Comment: The problem is that `where sal := v_sal` should be `where sal = v_sal`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues within the code. Convert to the one as below:

```
declare
   type emp_record is record
   (v_empid emp1.empno % type,
    v_ename emp1.ename % type );

   emp_rec emp_record;
   v_sal emp1.sal%type:=&i_sal;

begin

   select empno,ename
     into emp_rec
     from emp1
    where sal = v_sal;

   dbms_output.put_line('The employee whose salary is ' || v_sal || 'has Employee Id ' 
                        || emp_rec.v_empid || 'and his name is ' || emp_rec.v_ename); 
end;
/
```

Whenever it prompts for the `i_sal`, you'll input the desired salary parameter value.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=73824ac321792e5f9ba6ab07edac64cf)</kbd>

If you have multiple records to be manipulated as @APC mentioned, such as more than one people has the same salary,you'll need such a loop statement :

```
declare
   type emp_record is record
   (v_empid emp1.empno % type,
    v_ename emp1.ename % type,
    v_sal   emp1.sal % type);

   emp_rec emp_record;
   v_sal emp1.sal%type:=&i_sal;

   cursor c_emp is
   select empno,ename,sal
     into emp_rec
     from emp1
    where sal = v_sal;
begin

  open c_emp;
  loop
    fetch c_emp into emp_rec;
   exit when c_emp%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line('The employee whose salary is ' || emp_rec.v_sal || ' has Employee Id ' 
                         || emp_rec.v_empid || ' and his name is ' || emp_rec.v_ename); 
  end loop;
  close c_emp;
end;
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=18976b2bf7c62146a2323b5aeffbddc9)</kbd>

Comment: It was very helpful BarBaros Ozhan.

Comment: If it's helpful, then please accept the answer @ShubhamTiwari

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method to fix that particular problem is to use aggregation:

```
select max(empno), max(ename)
into emp_rec
from emp1
where sal = v_sal;
```

An aggregation query with no `group by` always returns exactly one row.

That said, the more correct method is to handle the exception that is generated by not having a matching value.  You will also need to handle exceptions for duplicate values as well.

Comment: But the columns in the result set might not come from the same row. Consider empno:1, ename:Gordon and empno:3, ename:Belayer. The above query would return empnp:3 ename:Gordon. That might be misleading and unexpected.

Comment: `where sal := v_sal` - here must be equal sign `=`.